# Javascript stop rotate animation after rotating to a certain degree

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to make an image rotate to a certain degree after pressing a button . I have followed some internet tutorials to implement the base of my code.

I am using an arrow.png image from the internet and I want it rotate with an animation with +45deg every time I am pressing a button .
For example, the arrow is pointing right as default, after pressing the button I want to make it rotate clockwise to the bottom right corner. From that position, pressing again should make it rotate with the tip pointing down etc.

My problem is that, after pressing the button my animation is stuck in a loop and I don't know how to make it rotate with +45deg without going from 0deg every time I am doing it.

This is my code

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.RotateValueHolder = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  StartImageRotateFunction() {
    this.RotateValueHolder.setValue(0);
    Animated.timing(this.RotateValueHolder, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    }).start(() => this.StartImageRotateFunction());
  }

  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
    this.StartImageRotateFunction(0);
  };

  render() {
    const RotateData = this.RotateValueHolder.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '45deg'],
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.Image
          source={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/2x/arrow.png' }}
          style={{
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            transform: [{ rotate: RotateData }],
          }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text>Apasa aici</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.countContainer}>
          <Text>Ai apasat aici de {this.state.count} times</Text>
          <Text>{this.estedisperat()} </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your sample some redundant fragments, see explanation where they are commented out.

Here is a working [example](https://snack.expo.io/Zs3WYRnNT)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.RotateValueHolder = new Animated.Value(0);

/*
  It seem that it could be defined only once, 
  recalculate the same transform on every render is not necessary  
*/
    this.RotateData = this.RotateValueHolder.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ['0deg', '45deg'],
    });
  }

  StartImageRotateFunction() {
   /*
Loop problem starts here, omit
This one set rotate value to 0 on very call 
    // this.RotateValueHolder.setValue(0);   
  */   
    Animated.timing(this.RotateValueHolder, {
      /*
      Next problem.
      instead times to times set target value to 1 you should use cuurent value from state 
      // toValue: 1,
      */
      toValue: this.state.count,
      duration: 1000,
      easing: Easing.linear,
    })
     /*
     call `.start()` is required, but when you pass callback into
     it will invoked just after animation ends,
     in your case it had start looping 
     // .start(() => this.StartImageRotateFunction());
     */
     .start();
  }

  state = {
    count: 0,
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    }, () => this.StartImageRotateFunction());
    /*
     Last, bat not least, start animation after set new state
    // this.StartImageRotateFunction(0);
    */
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Animated.Image
          source={{ uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/plasticine/2x/arrow.png' }}
          style={{
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            transform: [{ rotate: this.RotateData /* `this`, due to moved in constructor */ }],
          }}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text>Apasa aici</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.countContainer}>
          <Text>Ai apasat aici de {this.state.count} times</Text>
          <Text>{
/* just replace absent function with expected behavior */ 
`rotated ${(this.state.count * 45) % 360}`
}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from your example here as it looks like the `Animated` function you're using is not being imported. Whenever you're looking at posing a question always try and provide the smallest working example. It greatly helps people trying to give you a response.

Another thing that looks like there might be a problem is that your `transform: [{ rotate: RotateData }]` line isn't attached to any other state which means that future presses won't be able to inform the number of rotations that need to happen. I would expect some sort of line like

`const degrees = this.state.count * 45`; to denote the number of degrees that the arrow needs to have rotated after each click.

Also, when posing your question, try to isolate the problems into independent pieces. You mention two things:

- Your animation gets stuck in a loop
- You don't know how to rotate the button

As far as the second bullet above, see this example

Something to note about your `Animate` function is that it takes a domain and range. In order to ensure that your rotation and click count always stays within a specified range, you can use the `%` modulo operator. See the simplified example I created here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-bas-bs7fw

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const increment = () => setCount(count + 1);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
      <div>{count * 45}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```